# VHDL - creating a variable number of signals

Tags: for-loop, vhdl

I'm creating a full adder with a variable number of bits. I've got a component that is a half-adder which takes in three inputs (the two bits to add, and a carry in bit) and gives 2 outputs (one bit output and a carry out bit).

I need to tie the carry out of one half-adder to the carry in of another. And I need to do this a variable number of times (if I'm adding 4 digit numbers, I'll need 4 half adders. If I'm doing 32 bit numbers, I'll need 32 half adders).
I was going to tie the carry outs of one half-adder to the carry in of another using signals, but I don't know how to create a variable number of signals.

I can instantiate a variable number of half-adders using a for-loop in a process, but since signals are defined outside of processes, I can't use a for loop for it. I don't know how I should tie the half-adders together.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to write an adder in VHDL is not to worry about full adders and half adders, but just type:

`a <= b + c;`

where a,b and c are `signed` or `unsigned`

95% of the time, the synthesis tools will do a better job than you would.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want variable-width signals not variable numbers of signals

Your signals need to be `std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)` for example - and then you wire up the bits of those signals to your half-adders appropriately.

Of course, as those signals are numbers, then don't use `std_logic_vector` use `signed` or `unsigned` (and the ieee.numeric_std lib).

And (as Philippe rightly points out) unless this is a learning exercise, just use the `+` operator.

Comment: You can use a 'generic' to define the width of your full adder, so that you have to change the 4 into 32 only in one place (http://vhdlguru.blogspot.be/2010/03/generics-in-vhdl-construction-of.html).

Comment: If you would want to use a variable number of signals that are not of the type std_logic, you can use VHDL arrays (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418432/hardware-representation-for-arrays-in-vhdl?rq=1)

Comment: @Vortexfive : Instead of a generic you can also use the 'high attribute and an unconstrained array on the port map.  But those are probably steps for later on in the OP's learning process.  Personally I'd avoid the 'vhdlguru' - the reasons why are a long post in themselves which I haven't found time to write yet...